# Is it possible to "spoof" a webcam feed?

Tags: c#, video, webcam

For example, [ManyCam](http://manycam.com/) allows you to sort of spoof webcam feeds. You run it and it looks to other programs like its a legitimate stream, even though it can mess with the background and what not.

Is it possible to do something like that in C#.NET? Basically, I want to completely override/spoof a webcam stream, so that other applications will pick up this "webcam" and see it as a real webcam (but its really any image/video I want to send). How might I create a webcam stream without a webcam, and then run any image or video over it? Is that even possible in C#?

Comment: This looks like a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/440017/net-options-stream-video-files-as-webcam-image.  A search for "fake webcam" gives this for $28: http://www.camersoft.com/fake-webcam.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ManyCam gets away with this because it installs as a device driver.  It connects to the video devices and then echoes this information via its own device driver.

You would need to write a driver so that it appears as an available video device to submit your feed.

Very interesting idea, could be useful for testing webcam enabled apps.

Answer (score 0):

ManyCam can playback video/gif images: [manual](http://www.manycam.com/user_guide/?ver=26#SourcesTab)  So I'm not sure what ability you're looking to add.

But yeah to do it yourself you'd need to create a device driver that you can feed a source into